# spotify api get user data like playlists via API?

Tags: api, spotify

i got a premium account of [spotify](http://www.spotify.com) and then registered an app and then got the key file . now i want to get the plalylist and user data of any user who uses my application.
I searched around the web but did not found any way to get the user data like access_token in facebook graph api.
Any body help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i got Plasylist.bnk from the installation directory, and its solved now. thanks all